# Error on peatio installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I followed the installation steps found @ https://github.com/peatio/peatio/blob/master/doc/setup-ubuntu.md, however it always throws me an error "rake aborted!" when I run "bundle exec rake db:setup".
I tried two fresh instals of ubuntu 14.04 LTS, tried installing different versions of ruby 2.1.2, 2.1.1 and 2.1.3, and also cloning stable branch besides master, with no luck. I don´t really know where else to look at. Can anyone give me some light on this issue? Thanks a lot.

ERROR:

```
user@user:~/peatio$ bundle exec rake db:setup --trace
rake aborted!
(): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:21:in `raw'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in '
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'
/home/user/peatio/config/application.rb:16:in `'
/home/user/peatio/config/application.rb:15:in `'
/home/user/peatio/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/user/peatio/Rakefile:5:in `'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
user@user:~/peatio$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ruby 2.5.3 and latest bundler install. Use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Debian 9 for setup.